# Castle Windsor: OnCreate for BaseOnDescriptor

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

As you may have known, 
'OnCreate' method is used for ComponentRegistration class, created by Component.For<> invocation.
Why Classes.FromAssembly lacks this feature?
Why we can't use OnCreate for every class in specified namespace.
Is there a workaround?

I would like to have it done as follows:

```
Classes
  .FromThisAssembly()
  .InSameNameSpaceAs<TInterface>()
  .OnCreate<TInterface>( instance => instance.Method());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Classes` lets you register components based on conventions, so it doesn't handle individual components but rather collections of components; you cannot configure them individually with the fluent interface. However you can use the [`Configure`](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#Additional_filtering_and_configuration_4) method which lets you manipulate each component to suit your needs.

```
Classes
  .FromThisAssembly()
  .InSameNameSpaceAs<TInterface>()
  .Configure(c => {
       c.OnCreate( instance => instance.Method())
  });
```

There are also a `ConfigureFor` and `ConfigureIf` methods that let you filter what components in the convention you want to process.

Comment: What should I interpret 'Component' in ConfigureFor<Component> expression? Should it be taken as 'all descendants of Component' or just Component itself?

Comment: I don't know exactly, never used the syntax, but it would make sense that it is for the component itself. Better check it yourself, though, I couldn't find documentation

Comment: @Dmitry, did you test the followup question you had about the scope of components / descendants of components?